# static assert c++ - constant expression error

Tags: c++, static-assert

I'm trying to use the static_assert :

```
static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::max() <= std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() , "T maximum should be smaller than size_t maximum" );
```

but I get an error on compilation

> Expected constant expression

I do have an expression so whats the problem ?

Comment: Compiler used and version? What's `T`? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *"I do have an expression so whats the problem ? "* It is not constant. (It's not a *constant* expression.) For example, in VS up to and including VS2013, there is no `constexpr`, hence (evaluated) function calls may not appear in a context where a constant expression is required.

Comment: I do use VS2013 , so how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a compiler without `constexpr` use the appropriate C library `MAX` names such as `SIZE_MAX` from `<stdint.h>`.

Alternatively, for an unsigned type such as `size_t` you can just use `size_t(-1)`.

See (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) for a list.